# Downloading Webcomic Saving Blank Files

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a script for downloading the Questionable Content webcomic. It looks like it runs okay, but the files it downloads are empty, only a few kb in size.

```
#import Web, Reg. Exp, and Operating System libraries
import urllib, re, os

#RegExp for the EndNum variable
RegExp = re.compile('.*<img src="http://www.questionablecontent.net/comics.*')

#Check the main QC page
site = urllib.urlopen("http://questionablecontent.net/")
contentLine = None

#For each line in the homepage's source...
for line in site.readlines():
    #Break when you find the variable information
    if RegExp.search(line):
        contentLine = line
    break

#IF the information was found successfuly automatically change EndNum
#ELSE set it to the latest comic as of this writing
if contentLine:
    contentLine = contentLine.split('/')
    contentLine = contentLine[4].split('.')
    EndNum = int(contentLine[0])
else:
    EndNum = 2622

#First and Last comics user wishes to download
StartNum = 1
#EndNum = 2622

#Full path of destination folder needs to pre-exist
destinationFolder = "D:\Downloads\Comics\Questionable Content"

#XRange creates an iterator to go over the comics
for i in xrange(StartNum, EndNum+1):

    #IF you already have the comic, skip downloading it
    if os.path.exists(destinationFolder+"\\"+str(i)+".png"):
        print "Skipping Comic "+str(i)+"..."
        continue

    #Printing User-Friendly Messages
    print "Comic %d Found. Downloading..." % i

    source = "http://www.questionablecontent.net/comics/"+str(i)+".png"

    #Save image from XKCD to Destination Folder as a PNG (As most comics are PNGs)
    urllib.urlretrieve(source, os.path.join(destinationFolder, str(i)+".png"))

#Graceful program termination
print str(EndNum-StartNum) + " Comics Downloaded"
```

Why does it keep downloading empty files? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the server doesn't serve you the image if your user agent isn't set. Below is a sample code for Python 2.7, which should give you an idea regarding how to make your script work.

```
import urllib2
import time

first = 1
last = 2622

for i in range(first, last+1):
    time.sleep(5) # Be nice to the server! And avoid being blocked.
    for ext in ['png', 'gif']:
        # Make sure that the img dir exists! If not, the script will throw an
        # IOError
        with open('img/{}.{}'.format(i, ext), 'wb') as ifile:
            try:
                req = urllib2.Request('http://www.questionablecontent.net/comics/{}.{}'.format(i, ext))
                req.add_header('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
                ifile.write(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
                break
            except urllib2.HTTPError:
                continue
    else:
        print 'Could not find image {}'.format(i)
        continue
    print 'Downloaded image {}'.format(i)
```

You may want to change your loop into something that resembles your loop (check whether  the image has been downloaded previously etc.). This script will try to download all images from `<start>.<ext>` to `<end>.<ext>`, where `<ext>` is either gif or png.

Comment: Thanks, gave it a whirl there, seems to be working great. Thanks again!